# Joukowski Aerofoil Plot

Tags: complex-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I've just had a go at plotting flow around aerofoils and I've come across a problem where I can't spot where I've gone wrong.

I've previously worked out that the complex potential flow around a disk with added circulation (to satisfy the stagnation point being on the trailing edge) is given by $$\Omega (z)=U\left(ze^{-i\phi}+\frac{e^{i\phi}}{z}\right)+2iUsin\phi ln(z).$$

To transform the disk into an aerofoil shape, I (think!) I need to apply the Joukowski Mapping to an off-centred disk. I can then find the inverse of this map and substitute this into the previously known flow around a disk and plot the streamlines.

Now to do this, I thought to first apply an affine transformation to map the disk to an off-centred disk that passes through the point $\zeta=1$ and encloses $\zeta=-1$ (the two critical points of the Joukowski transform), and then apply the Joukowski map, work out the inverse and substitute into the known flow. So here goes: first I apply the transformation

$$w=\alpha z +\beta,$$

such that $\alpha = |1-\beta|$. This maps the disk $|z|\leq 1$ to a disk centred $\beta$, radius $\alpha$. Then applying the Joukowski map $$\zeta=\frac{1}{2}\left(w+\frac{1}{w}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha z +\beta+\frac{1}{\alpha z +\beta}\right),$$ and solving for z, $$z=\frac{\zeta-\beta+\zeta\sqrt{(1-\frac{1}{\zeta^2})}}{\alpha} .$$

Substituting this into the known flow and plotting the imaginary part, if I simply shift the disk along the real axis, I get roughly what I expect (the green line being the dividing streamline):

[image]

But if I shift the disk upwards, whilst I get the right sort of shape, it's clearly not correct:
[image]

[image]

If anyone could give me a push as to where I've gone wrong it would be appreciated. I can't spot it in the code or the workings at all. Thanks!

Comment: I think $\ln(z)$ is the source of problem. How do you interpret it in the formula for $\Omega$? It's not a single-valued function. Maple has to make a branch cut somewhere, which introduces discontinuity, something you do not want. The larger issue  is: with the presence of circulation the flow is not a potential flow, thus it cannot be plotted like a potential flow. The formula for $\Omega$ is correct locally, and if you take derivatives of $\Omega$, you do get the unambiguous value of the velocity vector.  You could plot that as a vector field.

Comment: @PostNoBills I think you would take a branch cut to remove the interval $(-1,1)$, but (if that's right) I'm not sure how to show this on Maple. I think I understand your second point. Thanks again.